# Is mb_* necessary to replace single-byte characters from a multibyte string?

Tags: php, utf-8

Let's say I have an `UTF-8` text like this:

```
âàêíóôõ <br> âàêíóôõ <br> âàêíóôõ
```

I want to replace `<br>` with `<br />`. Do I need to use `mb_str_replace` or I can use `str_replace` ?

Consindering `<` `b` `r` `/` `>` are all single byte char?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) is binary-safe and UTF-8 is a bijective encoding, you can use `str_replace`, even if search string or replacement contains multi-byte characters, as long as all three parameters are encoded as UTF-8.

That's why there isn't an `mb_str_replace` function in the first place.

If your encoding is not bijective - i.e. there are multiple representations of the same string, for example `<` in UTF-7, which can be expressed both as `'+ADw-'` and `'<'`, you should convert all strings to the same (bijective) encoding, apply `str_replace`, and then convert the strings to the target encoding.

Comment: So basically with UTF-8 I can forget the `mb_str_replace` ? Which other mb_* I can forget considering `UTF-8` ?

Comment: For example `mb_substr_count();` ?

Comment: @yes123 Added an explanation of what bijective means. There is no `mb_str_replace`. If you know you're dealing with UTF-8, you can use the regular functions for everything that does not involve numeric indices, and where the corresponding regular function is binary-safe.

Comment: Updated the comment. `substr_count` is not binary-safe, therefore you can **not** use it instead of `mb_substr_count`.

Answer (score 2):

[Reference for manipulating UTF-8 strings safely in PHP](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160515185835/http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8)). There is no hard-and-fast rule. Some native PHP string functions functions can operate safely on utf-8, some can with care, and some cannot.

There is no `mb_str_replace()`. Notice the section "UTF-8 Safe Functionality": `explode()` and `str_replace()` are safe as long as all three arguments to it are valid UTF-8 strings.